# debug ssis package - reload InnerPackage.dtsx

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssis

I used the wizard to build a package that loops through my tables does whatever.  It has worked forever and now I have to change it.  How on earth do I debug this thing?  When I try to run it from bids, it opens InnerPackage.dtsx for editing and then asks me if I want to reload it (since it has changed since the last iteration of the loop).  I can't press yes or no fast enough to prevent the package from failing because 'process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'.  How can I keep this from opening so that I can get to the point that it's actually failing when the server runs the package and fix it.
Many thanks.

Comment: Why is the package changing? It shouldn't be changing from one iteration to the next. How are you calling this inner pacakge? Execute Package Task inside the loop?

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  I think it has to change from one iteration to the next doesn't it, otherwise how can you perform the same task on a different table - base on the tableschema.xml definitions?  Yes it is an Execute taks inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The wizard uses some behind the scenes "magic" to do it's work that makes it really difficult to debug. You might be best off recreating the package yourself. More work, but you can debug it much more easily.

Comment: I'm all for that!  How does one go about learning how to duplicate their magic without the side effects - i.e. loop through the tables and creat a dynamic package that can run in a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Put a Breakpoint on it, or on the step before it.

Alternatively, you may need to copy the package, then open it with BIDS Helper and regenerate all of the IDs (GUIDs).  (BIDs helper can do this in one step for you).

Comment: I can't put a breakpoint in because my code shows as all one line - which I would dearly love to change too.  Bids Helper is cool, thanks for that suggestion.  I moved the file(s) and tried resetting the GUIDs - no love.